# Success and Failures of Alpha/Beta release

Tags: usability-testing, testing, beta

We have been building a new digital product (cross-platform mobile app) from the ground up and through the prototyping and development phases we have conducted user studies on the usability of the product.

Now we are at the point where we have a minimum viable product ready for an Alpha and Beta release. and I'm thinking of **1.** distributing tasks to be performed in app on a daily basis and **2.** distributing a questionnaire/survey type document to facilitate feedback from participants.

### My question, as the Product Designer, is how do I best measure the success and failures of the Alpha/Beta release versions?

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit:

As I haven't made any advise on any product to measure A/B testing at it's best, I assumed you also might find a tool by googling as **[this sample research](https://mashable.com/2015/01/30/ab-testing-tools/#9OyJDAFboaqn)** gives a couple of examples.

I'm using my company's own product to measure the A/B test on e-mails but at the end of the day, I prefer to take the data from there and use them under one roof I created once with the other datas I gathered from different sources. I also agree it'd be more preferable to use that tool if there is only one solution to be able to watch every possible data but

> Simply creating 2 seperate excel document for A & B to keep updated
> with different datas with the exactly same sorted sheets is the best
> way I could achieved yet.

Answer (score 1):

Successes and failures are specific to your app. You should define metrics that aligned on your business objectives / UX design choices.

Examples of metrics can be objective measures such as error rates, completion time, time spent on app, or subjective such as "how easy - difficult would you rate this app", etc.

If you're looking for more qualitative and detailed feedback, you could use [Indeemo](https://indeemo.com/) and have your users record their impression of the app in audio / video. This is also ideal to collect data on the context of use, if it's something that matters for your app.